# weird storyboard item positions in Xcode8

Tags: xcode

I have been having a problem with the Xcode8 storyboard. Whenever I embed a table view in a navigation controller, the various items (labels, buttons, etc.) that I drag into the cell will have a weird vertical offset. Basically, if there is a label in the cell, I will have to click below where it actually is to select it. Anybody else ever had this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: and it only does it "sometimes." However, if there is a bar button item, it is always offset in this way.